# Substitute class method with a string in Python

Tags: python, function, md5, substitution

Lets say that I want to do this

```
hashlibAlgo = "md5"
Hash= hashlib.**"hashlibAlgo"**("blah blah blah").hexdigest()
```

How can I do that. If I substitute the name of a method with a string it obviously does not work. How can I make it work? In powershell is easy, but I cannot figure it in Python.

Comment: +1 for being one of the best illustrations of when `getattr` is useful. (Usually this kind of question is a sign of a novice wanting to solve a silly problem the wrong way. But here, you're trying to solve a perfectly reasonable problem the right way.)

Answer (score 7):

You can get function to execute with `getattr`:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlibAlgo = "md5"
>>> getattr(hashlib, hashlibAlgo)("blah blah blah").hexdigest()
'55e562bfee2bde4f9e71b8885eb5e303'
```

Comment: Beat me to it. ( I guess that's what I get for editing :P )  +1

Comment: (0_0) First time I see that function man. It is awesome. Thank you for the quick reply and great solution.

Comment: @JuanC. -- It also takes an optional 3rd argument:  `getattr(thing,'string',return_this_if_thing_has_no_string_attr)`